# Error "Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0"

Tags: php, mysql

This is my error:

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL        result index 53 in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\class.rooms.php on line 35

This is the line in the coding:

```
return mysql_result(
       dbquery(
           "SELECT " . $var . " FROM rooms WHERE id = '" . $roomId . "' LIMIT 1"
       ), 0);
```

Comment: If you're early in the game, you might want to switch from the mysql function to mysqli or pdo. The (old) mysql function has been deprecated and is no longer supported by php. mysqli and pdo are better alternatives.

Comment: Probably the query fails,do a var_dump.

Comment: Please use more specific titles than "I have an error in my code"; if everyone used such a title, the question index here would be rather useless `;-)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $var and $roomId are correctly populated **,** it might he useful to test your code excluding the dbquery function which seems to be a user defined function **:**

```
$query_temp = "SELECT " .$var ." FROM rooms WHERE id = '" .$roomId ."' LIMIT 1";

/*
 * This is for test purpose and in production you would not want to display neither the query nor error to the user.
 */

$result_temp = mysql_query( $query_temp ) or die ("Error in query: $query_temp. " .mysql_error( ) );

//  var_dump( mysql_fetch_array ( $result_temp ) );

return( $result_temp );
```

> As already commented by shmuli it is worth to switch to mysqli or pdo in the beginning itself

Comment: You sir are a genuis, this fixed my problem!

Comment: _As my answer fixed your problem you might want to consider accepting it as it might also help others that come across this question . Thanks_ **. . .**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, function dbquery is unfamiliar to me. I know mysql_query, but maybe it's your own method. The problem is, most possibly, that your query returns no rows.
Try debugging with

```
$result = ..query..
if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
    echo "No rows.";
```